# What should I do when the correct answer to a question changes over time?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, accepted-answer

My question concerns [how to perform boost::filesystem copy_file with overwrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829468/how-to-perform-boostfilesystem-copy-file-with-overwrite). I asked the question, and at the time selected the correct answer. However, time passes and libraries get updated, and now a different answer is actually correct.

I should probably select this new answer as the correct answer, but I feel bad for the person that will lose 15 reputation points even though is answer was the a good answer at that given point in time.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I should probably select this new answer as the correct answer, but I feel bad for the person that will lose 15 reputation points even though is answer was the a good answer at that given point in time.

The answer probably got plenty of upvotes already being an accepted answer. It's more important to follow up and select what *you* believe to be the correct answer.

Certainly more important than a few reputation points in the big scheme of things.

Comment: If I didn't pose the question (and hence can't bless the new-correct answer), should I downvote the originally-correct answer? That also seems unfair, but it's the only option available. (After leaving a comment.)

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this phenomena many times. Sometimes new questions are started, and in some cases that is good because, some of the upvotes in the old questions wouldn't be upvotes today.

A good example is the questions about an IDE for Scala:

- [What are the good Scala IDEs at the start of 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127381/what-are-the-good-scala-ides-at-the-start-of-2010) (new)
- [Which IDE for Scala 2.8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615196/which-ide-for-scala-2-8) (older)
- [Which is the best IDE for Scala development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419207/which-is-the-best-ide-for-scala-development) (oldest)

Comment: **Related:** http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47984/what-to-do-if-an-out-of-date-questionanswers-already-exists/47986#47986

Comment: I think this works better for general questions, like in your example, than for focused questions about a small detail like in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this dilemma again today from
[Hadoop: specify yarn queue for distcp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540752/hadoop-specify-yarn-queue-for-distcp)

If I had my druthers, I would prefer to see both answers in this example marked with a check (or alternate glyph) and a tag (for the answer, not the question) indicating the version numbers when each answer applies (v1.x in one case; v2.x and v3.x in the other).

I personally don't agree with downvoting the antiquated answer, even if the technology is EOL. Knowledge can be certainly true in the past, probably true in the present, and possibly true in the future. StackExchange is no different.

Answer (score 2):

I found that performing an **EDIT** without deleting the previous content but specifying the reason of the update is a good option, for example a case where the correct answer can change over time is in an update of version of Windows (7, 8, 8.1 , 10 and now 11).

Here is an example I did in **SO** to the question "*How do I get monitor resolution in Python?*": https://stackoverflow.com/a/56336303/9756894

Comment: Related (2021-10-08): *[Version labels for answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370640)*

Comment: Posts shouldn't contain meta information like "UPDATE" (that is what the revision history is for). Other meta information belongs in comments. The post should appear as if it was written today. It doesn't matter when something was written. For example, use version ranges (and/or date ranges) instead for different versions of software and operating systems.