# What to do with out of date answers

Tags: support, old-questions, wrong-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do if an out of date question+answers already exists?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47984/what-to-do-if-an-out-of-date-questionanswers-already-exists)

I have arrived at a question via goggle and stack overflow appears again.

[Is there a way to programmatically access Google's search engine results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445308/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-access-googles-search-engine-results)

The answers however are out of date as the APIs suggested are now obsolete.

What can be done to highlight this fact should I edit the answers or something else?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't edit the existing answers to state that their methods are obsolete, but rather proceed with your research and, when coming across the relevant information *post your own, up to date* answer on the topic.

Though the swathes of votes might long have died down, the integrity of the data is most important, and keeping certain things for historical purposes can be beneficial (some might still be stuck using obsolete APIs), and so your contribution ought to help people over time - after all, it brought you to *that* question / answer.

If there are no other questions and answers on that exact topic, then you *might* consider asking and, if you find out prior to being provided an answer, answering your own question (though this might be frowned upon in the realm of SO, where questions come thick and fast and doing so is not necessary to aid in populating the site) - this is probably a last resort.