# How bold should old accepted answers be edited when they become outdated?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, community-wiki

Case in point:
[How do you assert that a certain exception is thrown in JUnit 4 tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156503)
The accepted answer is not the best answer anymore, yet visitors to this page asking for this question are likely not to know any better and to copy&paste the first answer.

Consequently, I can:

- upvote other answers, hoping they'll catch up.
- comment to ask to change the accepted answer.
- edit the accepted answer to point out it is outdated.
- edit the accepted answer to summarize all options (e.g. treat it as a community wiki).

Is there any guidance on that?

I did not find any similar meta question, only related ones where the original asker thinks about changing which answer is accepted, like: [Change accepted answer after some years?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335277)

Edit: some more search gives me:

- [What to do if an out of date question+answers already exists?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47984)

which might be a duplicate, and which seems to suggest to just boldly edit the answer (using best judgement). **EDIT: So i just did that, feel free to flag this questio nas duplicate and review my edit to the given accepted answer**

In comparison, Wikipedia follows the [Be bold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Be_bold) philosophy to allow fixing bad information as early as possible.

Comment: Editing the currently accepted answer is definitely one of the best ways to ensure it stays updated. Your edit was well done, preserving the original content while mentioning the updated solution.