# Votes and Timing

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do when the correct answer to a question changes over time?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47962/what-to-do-when-the-correct-answer-to-a-question-changes-over-time)

Say a question is asked/answered as per usual and after some long period (say 2-3 years) a change in technology or otherwise causes an answer that has less votes than the originally accepted answer to be more relevant (or correct) *currently*.

What is the expected procedure here?  Should the original answer be down-voted?  Should the question and its originally accepted answer be tagged somehow as irrelevant/redundant?  Should the original question/answer be left and a new question (exactly the same) be asked to allow the answer/vote process to begin again?

Answer (score 1):

> Should the original answer be down-voted?

No, it should not. The answer was correct when the question was asked.

> Should the question and its originally accepted answer be tagged somehow as irrelevant/redundant?

If the question were only relevant for the user asking it, the question should have been already closed as too localized. If you do tag as irrelevant questions that are 4 years old, then you should flag all the questions asked 4 years ago.

> Should the original question/answer be left and a new question (exactly the same) be asked to allow the answer/vote process to begin again?

You should only ask a question if you have a problem to solve, not to ask the exactly same question that has been asked 4 years ago.
If the question doesn't contain any updated answer, then the right thing to do is to add a new answer that is updated for what the actual situation is.